# C++ SafeSingleton 3 level inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a templated SafeSingleton class, Base class which is derived from SafeSingleton and implements some base methods. I want to have class that is derived from Base and can be accessed via instance() method of SafeSingleton. The problem is that when I am trying to access Derived::instance() it returns the pointer to a Base class and the compiler doesn't know anything about methods of derived class. What should I do to make below code work.

```
template<class T>
class SingleTon {
public:
    static T* instance()
    {
        return holder().instance;
    }
protected:
    template<class I>
    struct Holder
    {
        Holder() : instance(new I())
        {
        }

        I* instance;
    };

    static Holder<T> &holder()
    {
        static Holder<T> holder;
        return holder;
    }
};

// Hopefully issue is here, I am never creating SingleTon<Derived>, but how can it be done?
class Base : public SingleTon<Base> {
public:
    Base() = default;
    void printBase() {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() = default;
    void printDerived() {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived::instance()->printBase();
    Derived::instance()->printDerived(); // Here is the error
    //Error: main.cpp:57:26: error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘printDerived’
   //57 |     Derived::instance()->printDerived();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class D>
class Base : public SingleTon<D> {
```

and

```
class Derived : public Base <Derived>
```

and ... done?

If you want to put Base's non-`D`dependent methods in a cpp file, you'll have to get fancy.  Have `BaseImp` that does not derive from `SingleTon`, put code there.  Have `Base<D>` derive from it and write forwarding glue to it `BaseImpl`.  But you probably don't need this.

Comment: Now as I see I can't call Base::instance()->someBaseMethod(), because I should provide template argument (Base<Base>? Don't think so). Also this solution is not for me as my Base class is derived from QObject(QT) which doesn't like templates.